# Is it possible to set X-Accel-Expires in web.config for ASP.NET?

Tags: azure, iis, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have a c# ASP.Net application with an NGINX server as a reversed proxy in front of it. I add a version query parameter for every CSS and JS file I include and all images are immutable. For some JS files however I can't add these parameters so NGINX will cache them for the entire length of the cache control header. 
It is possible to overrule the cache control header for proxies by setting the X-Accel-Expires header. However, I don't know how to do this in IIS (web.config) and can't find out either. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a configuration in the root `web.config`, it simply adds `X-Accel-Expires: 10` for `assets/jquery-1.10.1.min.js`.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <location path="assets/jquery-1.10.1.min.js">
        <system.webServer>
            <httpProtocol>
                <customHeaders>
                    <add name="X-Accel-Expires" value="10" />
                </customHeaders>
            </httpProtocol>
        </system.webServer>
    </location>
</configuration>
```

For more information: [Custom Headers <customHeaders>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/httpprotocol/customheaders/)